# JavaScript check incorrectly allows numbers in an input field

Tags: javascript

I have an assignment for school that consists of checking whether or not a value is an integer or not. Here is the actual assignment notes:

1. Write JavaScript™ code that anticipates and handles an error for an expected numeric field. This code is executed on keypress, and the entered value is saved for you in a variable called enteredChar. Include the try block of JavaScript™ statements needed to check if the character is not a number or a non-alphanumeric character, or if you throw an error message.

My code is as follows:

```
function numCheck() {
 var enteredChar = document.getElementById('numeric_field').value;

 var pattern = new RegExp('/^\d+$/'); // numbers only match

 if (pattern.test(enteredChar)) {
     alert("All good!");
 } else {
 try {
         throw new Error("Invalid numerical character(s) given!");
     } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
     }
 }
```

}

The html is as follows:

```
<form>
Enter Numeric Value: <input type="text" id="numeric_field" onkeypress="numCheck()">
</form>
```

Yet no matter what I do, if the first character is not a number, it works properly but when the second character is a number it also displays this alert dialog. Any help would be appreciated! I would like to check for each key pressed if each character is only numeric and if not, display the alert dialog, but if it is, display the alert dialog containing "All good!". I read that onkeyup and onkeydown are better suited for this, but since the assignment says use onkeypress I'm kind of stuck with using that.

Comment: your code is correct. if the first character is not a number, then the field value is not a number, independently of any further character entered.

Comment: oh so it doesn't treat each individually, only as a whole?

Comment: that's what you have coded !

Comment: yes but when I refresh the page and enter a number first, it also displays the alert dialog?

Comment: Please forgive my curiosity, but does your assignment really say `™` after `Javascript`?

Comment: Your variable `enteredChar` doesn't contain just a single character, it contains the entire contents of the input field. But your regular expression only matches one character.

Comment: yes, sorry, it's in the assignment document itself.. sorry.

Comment: how would I go about getting it to match the whole field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isNaN` is a nice solution!

But to correct your current code, here's my tips :

- Your pattern is not correct : `var pattern = new RegExp('^\\d+$');` is.
- Use `onkeyup` instead because you get the old value with `onkeypress`.

Comment: yes, I was noticing that even if I type a letter in the field that isn't a number it still lets it go through until after the next one is entered

Comment: Simpler to use a RegExp literal: `var pattern = /^\d+$/;`. The OP seems to want just integers, `isNaN` will allow floats and scientific notation (e.g. 8.64e7).

Answer (score 2):

You're making this much more difficult that it needs to be by using regex. In this case, it's much simpler (assuming you just need to know if it's a number or not, rather than some combination of letters and numbers) to use [`isNan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

```
function numCheck() {
 var enteredChar = document.getElementById('numeric_field').value;

 if (!isNaN(enteredChar)) {
     alert("All good!");
 } else {
 try {
         throw new Error("Invalid numerical character(s) given!");
     } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
     }
 }

}
```

Comment: although it's interesting that once you type in numbers than a non number value it doesn't matter what you type in after, it bugs out. That's expected isn't it?

Comment: You should do it in keyup instead of keypress since keypress is fired too early before the value property of the element is modified.

Comment: Yes, once you've entered a non-number value (even if you've already entered number values) it will error out, because "12a" is not an integer.

Comment: Given that the questions is "checking whether or not a value is an integer", then `isNaN` is a poor choice as it allows floats and scientific notation also. Given that the requirement is to check that a string is only digits, a regular expression is a good choice.